# awk changes field separator when saving file with three && conditions

Tags: bash, shell, awk, putty

I have a very specific awk question:

On this command, the output is a normal file with the ";" field separator.

```
awk -F\: '{ FS = ";";}{ if($1>=11414836 && $1<=11500000) print $0;}' /file.txt>/newfile.txt
```

Now, I need to add a third condition:

```
awk -F\: '{ FS = ";";}{ if($1>=11414836 && $1<=11500000 && $14=3294) print $0;}' /file.txt>/newfile.txt
```

The problem is that this third condition causes the field separator in the output change to a normal space (" ").

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: shouldn't it be `$14==3294`?

Comment: you have to set `OFS=";"`

Comment: You already got your answer but please read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins before trying to write awk scripts as what you have written so far makes no sense - you're setting FS to `:` before the script starts, processing the first input line with it set to that then setting it to `;` for the 2nd and subsequent lines, setting FS every time a line is read, putting a condition inside the action block, redundantly specifying the default action of `print $0`, escaping characters that don't need to be escaped, and adding spurious semi-colons all over the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is twofold (both stated in the comments):

1. You use `$14=3294` instead of `$14==3294`.  This sets `$14` to the value of `3294`, instead of comparing it.
2. When any of the fields are changed (as happens unintentionally), `awk` recomputes `$0`, and inserts the `OFS` between fields.